# Photon Propagator in QFT

Tags: quantum-electrodynamics, units, dimensional-analysis, propagator

Please forgive my temporary split-brain, but I'm a little thrown off by something when considering units at the moment.

In QED (depending on the guage), the photon propogator is written as
$<0|\mathcal{T}\mathcal{A}_\mu \mathcal{A}_\nu|0>=N\int d^4p {-ig_{\mu\nu}\over p^2+i\epsilon}e^{{i}{p\cdot\Delta x}}$

In terms of units I read the above as proportional to ${1\over p^2}\delta^4(x)$, somewhat similar/analogous to propagators for scalar fields.  The case of the scalar field propagator possessing such units is more clear to me as with the relativistic normalization it is easy to demonstrate $\Psi(x)^*\Psi(x)\propto {1\over p^2+m^2}\delta^4(x)$  (Unit-wise that is)

Unit-wise, however I usually  picture the vector field $\mathcal{A}$ as proportional to $p \over charge$, at least classically.  I would assume this should be fine because QED is consistent with classical electro-magnatism to the best of my knowledge.  But I am not entirely clear on how this leads to the units of the photon propagator being the same as those of the scalar propagator right now.

Currently I would like to reconcile these units with the form of the propagator given. Part of the problem is I'm not certain if they are using a different unit system for $\mathcal{A}$ in the quantum propagator case, or not.  Also useful would be more perspective on the correct way to interpret the units of  $<0|\mathcal{T}\mathcal{A}_\mu \mathcal{A}_\nu|0>$ in case I am overlooking something.  Hopefully this is a very simple  question, but if I have been unclear on something I will try to clarify.

Comment: You're correct, the fields have the same dimension they do classically, it's just that charge is dimensionless in natural units.

Comment: If I'm correct, I'm missing something.  For instance if $A^\mu=\int d^3 k ({1\over 2\pi \hbar})^3 {1\over 2 \omega}\sum_\lambda \epsilon^\mu  a e^{-{i\over\hbar}kx}+...$ how does one get units of momentum per charge out of that? It looks like ${p^2\over c}$